# Python -- Russell's paradox (lists,not sets)

Tags: python, nested-lists

I know that one can create lists within lists. But how many, exactly can I fit in one. I tried this in the IPython console:

```
In [1]: Alist = [1]

In [2]: Alist.append(Alist)

In [3]: Alist
Out[3]: [1, [...]]

In [4]: Alist[1]
Out[4]: [1, [...]]

In [5]: Alist[1][1]
Out[5]: [1, [...]]

In [6]: Alist[1][1][1]
Out[6]: [1, [...]]
```

Now I could go on forever trying to access `Alist[1][1][1][1]...[1]`, But how is this possible? Also, how come my machine hasn't run out of memory with this?
I use Python2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 if it helps.

Comment: All these lists you're accessing are really just the same list.

Comment: I agree, but the literal '1' should have been stored several times, right?

Comment: Try executing your program in http://pythontutor.com/, a great tool to visualize the content of memory during execution of a Python program. Essentially the answer is that you're storing a reference to the list, not a copy of the list.

Comment: Why would the `1` have been stored multiple times? It's not like you put it in multiple lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one object of finite size here:

You first create a list object with one element `[1]`, and then you create a reference to that object that you call `Alist`. When you append `Alist` to "istelf", you really just append the reference to your object to the object itself. You now have a list object with two elements: `1` and a reference to itself. No infinite memory involved here.

Try this to convince yourself:

```
Alist = [1]
Alist.append(Alist)
Alist[1][0] = 0
Alist[0]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but at what stage have I created "a reference to that object that I call Alist"?

Comment: `[1]` creates the object but does nothing with it and forgets about it. `Alist = [1]` creates the object and then creates a reference to that object. So now that object is 'remembered' and you can access it using its 'name' `Alist`. (Note that you can create multiple references to that same object like so `Blist = Alist`. This is totally analogous to saying that Shwarzy and Arnold Scharzenegger are essentially the same person.)