# Pythonic Russell's paradox

Tags: python, math

In Python, an example of a list that is in itself is `z` where

```
z = []
z.append(z)
print(z in z)  # True, since z contains a reference to itself
```

and an example of a list that is not in itself is `w` where

```
w = [1]
print(w in w)  # False, since w does not contain a reference to itself
```

Suppose for a moment that we had infinite computational power and memory. Then we could imagine infinite lists, such as the list of all even positive integers, which could be defined as the list `a` returned by the following code in the limit of `n` going to infinity:

`n = positive_integer`
`a = [i for i in range(n) if i%2==0]`

Could we similarly define a list `L`, in some limit, to be the list of all lists that are not in themselves? If so, we would seem to run into Russell's paradox which asks if `(L in L)` is true or false. For example, if we did something like the following:

`n = positive_integer` 
`L = [generate_random_list_not_in_itself() for _ in range(n)]`

is it the case that any imaginable implementation of the function generate_random_list_not_in_itself() would fail to capture **all** lists that are not in themselves, even in the limit of `n` going to infinity? And if so, why?

NOTE: I'm aware of the discussion at [Python -- Russell's paradox (lists,not sets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878815/python-russells-paradox-lists-not-sets), but which (as far as I can tell) doesn't ask the same question here.

Comment: "Then we could define L to be the list of all lists that are not in themselves." - no we couldn't. Lists don't work like that.

Comment: You might be able to define a generator, but not an infinite list.

Comment: For one thing, lists aren't timeless mathematical objects. They have state. They can be created, and they are (nondeterministically) destroyed. For another, there's no counterpart of naive set theory's unrestricted comprehension in Python. List comprehensions are more closely related to the axiom schemas of specification and replacement.

Comment: I see, so it seems that the paradox is avoided because we cannot construct such a list. But I still don't quite follow why in the (hypothetical) limit, we cannot construct such a list, when we can obviously create a list of some finite amount of lists. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: EDIT: I've added an example of a (hypothetical) infinite list to hopefully make the question I'm asking clearer.

Comment: *"Suppose for a moment that we had infinite computational power and memory."* You’re just working in math at this point, not Python. Is your question whether a countable set of random sets can contain itself? What’s your process for creating a random set?

Comment: @Ryan, I suppose I'm asking if a countable (python) list of random (python) lists can be `in` itself, which is maybe not the same as asking the same question about sets.

Comment: @sobes It is the same. What's a random list?

Comment: @Ryan That's part of my question, i.e. whether there are natural constraints on any implementation of generating an arbitrary list that is not in itself, that would disallow the paradox.

Answer (score 4):

Lists in Python are very different from sets in mathematics. Here is one simple explanation why we cannot construct L.

Suppose we accept your constraints. A `list` is an array, that is, a contiguous block somewhere in our infinite memory. The only way a computer (a Turing machine) can really populate an array is by item-wise assignment. List literals, comprehensions, casts from other types — ultimately all they do is allocate a block of memory and copy some data into it, chunk by chunk.

And here we run into a problem: if we allow infinite lists, there are *too many* of them, even if you limit yourself to lists that do not contain items other than lists. The set of all those lists is obviously at least infinite (it contains `[]`, `[[]]`, `[[],[]]`, `[[],[],[]]`, ...), but it is uncountable as well, because it also contains the list of “natural numbers” `[[], [[]], [[],[]], ...]` and all its subsets.

The process of populating L is clearly sequential (you can write out the sequence of indices as you populate them), so at best you can populate countably many elements, while L is uncountable. In a sense, even after an infinite amount of time has passed, you will still be left with items to add.

Hopefully this gives some insight as to why Russell's paradox is not applicable to Python.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It helped me formulate my question better (and which I've edited above). If I've understood you correctly, are you saying that we will "almost surely" never be able to capture all possible lists that are not in themselves, even with infinite computing time and memory?

Comment: As to `[generate() for _ in range(n)]`: this list is at best [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). As far as I know, there [are ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_recursion) to build uncountable objects, but you're not dealing with computers made of matter at this point, it's pure mathematical abstractions. There's no Python on the other side of infinity.

Comment: I see, so we won't ever run into this problem basically because there's no such thing as infinite computing power.

Comment: Honestly I don't think we would run into this problem even if we had infinite computing power, memory and/or time. Computers can only do so much, and building an uncountable list seems simply uncomputable (undecidable?).

Comment: Let me rephrase: Even if we had countably infinite computing power, we would not be able to list out all the lists that are not `in` themselves, the number of which is uncountably large. And there's no such thing as uncountably infinite computational power and/or memory.

Comment: @sobes Yes, that is pretty much what I was trying to say.

Comment: @sobes, as a part of generation of `L` you will have to generate a subset `R` of all lists that contain just numbers (and no inner lists). And if you think about it, you may notice that `R` is actually equivalent to the set all real numbers which has uncountable cardinality of the continuum

Comment: Since this is such an old question... I just posted an answer and would be curious to hear if others think it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the problem with Russell's paradox?

```
class MySelf:

    def __init__(self):
        self.me = MySelf()

MySelf()
```

This breaks due to infinite recursion, which is what is required for a set to contain itself.  Not exactly sure of the correct terminology, but an uncountable set has infinite breadth, whereas a set that contains itself has infinite depth.

So to me, the formulation of the problem seems faulty.